# Issue with converting ES query to sort nested objects by key and value to Java API (ES version 6.2)

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I would like to convert the below ES query to Java API

```
{
  "sort": [
{
  "nested_objects.Value": {
    "order": "desc",
    "nested_path": "nested_objects",
    "nested_filter": {
      "term": { "nested_objects.Key": "abc" }
      }
     }
   }
  ]
}
```

Tried to write a query as below but looks like the previously working methods are now deprecated in ES 6.2

```
FieldSortBuilder mySort = SortBuilders.fieldSort("nested_objects.Value")
                .setNestedFilter(QueryBuilders.nestedQuery("nested_objects",
                        QueryBuilders.termQuery("nested_objects.Key", "abc"), ScoreMode.Avg))
                .order(SortOrder.DESC);
```

setNestedFilter() appears to be deprecated any alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

I've copied the below text from this [Deprecated List Link](https://artifacts.elastic.co/javadoc/org/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/6.1.3/deprecated-list.html)

```
org.elasticsearch.search.sort.FieldSortBuilder.getNestedFilter()
set nested sort with FieldSortBuilder.setNestedSort(NestedSortBuilder) and retrieve with FieldSortBuilder.getNestedSort()

org.elasticsearch.search.sort.FieldSortBuilder.getNestedPath()
set nested sort with FieldSortBuilder.setNestedSort(NestedSortBuilder) and retrieve with FieldSortBuilder.getNestedSort()
```

You can see how they mentioned that you would need to make use of [NestedSortBuilder](https://artifacts.elastic.co/javadoc/org/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/6.1.3/org/elasticsearch/search/sort/NestedSortBuilder.html)

Below is what you can do. Simply create a Term Query using `QueryBuilder` and make use of it in `setFilter` method chaining to `setNestedSort`.

```
    QueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
            .must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("nested_objects.Key", "abc"));

    FieldSortBuilder mySort = SortBuilders.fieldSort("nested_objects.Value")
            .order(SortOrder.DESC)
            .setNestedSort(new NestedSortBuilder("nested_objects")
            .setFilter(query));
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: hey @praveen, was the above solution useful. Is there anything else you'd want or you are looking for?

Comment: is there a difference if I call setFilter on NestedSortBuilder itself?